# How to fix font-size in responsive UI?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, font-size

I have used bootstrap responsive for my site, i added font-size as `body { font-size: 10px !important; }` in my css file, but the style not apply to `h1`, `h2`, `href` tags and bootstrap `.btn` class,

I don't want to call the class/id for each above tags, how to change font-size according to the browser width?

Comment: You would need to use media queries to change the font-size at different browser widths. I suggest you also read the documentation in Bootstrap typography: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#type

Answer (score 0):

Try it...

```
body, h1, h2, .btn, a { font-size: 10px !important; }
```